# Upload image to the server in Android Using JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, imageview

I have read a lot of posts about uploading image to the server but i still have a problem. I m able to select the image from my device but it's not uploaded. I have no err .I receive a toast message that upload is successful but when i go to the upload folder, i cannot find the image.

I'm using this tutorial  [Upload Image on Server in Android Using JSON](http://geekonjava.blogspot.in/2014/03/upload-image-on-server-in-android-using.html)

my layout fragment_profil:

> ```
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
>             android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_pic"
>             android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_info_padd"
>             android:scaleType="fitCenter"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/button_selectpic"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/select_pic_btn" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/upload_pic_btn" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/messageText"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text=""
>             android:textColor="#000000"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
> ```

ProfilFragment :

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String imagepath=null;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil, container,
                false);
        uploadButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        btnselectpic = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        messageText  = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        upLoadServerUri = "http://My ip address/upload/upload_to_server.php";

private void selectProfilPic(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
    }

    private void uploadProfilPic(){

        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Uploading file...", true);
        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                          uploadFile(imagepath);

                     }
                   }).start();     
    }

     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

         if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
                profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

         }
        }

     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
         String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
         int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         return cursor.getString(column_index);
     }


     public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


           String fileName = sourceFileUri;

              HttpURLConnection conn = null;
              DataOutputStream dos = null;  
              String lineEnd = "\r\n";
              String twoHyphens = "--";
              String boundary = "*****";
              int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
              byte[] buffer;
              int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
              File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

              if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                pDialog.dismiss(); 

                Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                     messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                    }
                }); 

                return 0;

              }
              else
              {
                try { 

                   // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of  maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                      dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                     }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                      + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                    if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                              String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +"C:\\wampserver\\www\\uploads";
                              messageText.setText(msg);

                                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                         });                
                    }    

                    //close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

               } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                   pDialog.dismiss();  
                   ex.printStackTrace();

                  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });

                   Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
               } catch (Exception e) {

                   pDialog.dismiss();  
                   e.printStackTrace();

                   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });
                   Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
               }
               pDialog.dismiss();       
               return serverResponseCode; 

               } // End else block 
             }


     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.edit_profil_infos_btn:
            editProfileInfos(nom.getText().toString(), prenom.getText()
                    .toString(), email.getText().toString(), userID);
            break;
        case R.id.button_selectpic:
            selectProfilPic();
            break;
        case R.id.uploadButton:
            uploadProfilPic();
            break;
        }

    }
```

upload_to_server :

```
<?php
  require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `user` (image) VALUES ('".$file_path."')");
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode image, compress and encode to string like:

```
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                imagepath = getPath(mImageCaptureUri);

                BitmapFactory.Options options0 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options0.inSampleSize = 2;
                // options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                options0.inScaled = false;
                options0.inDither = false;
                options0.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos0 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos0);
                byte[] imageBytes0 = baos0.toByteArray();

                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes0, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And decode on serverside and save to folder:

```
$base = $_POST["encodedImage"];
        if (isset($base)) {

            $url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/uploads/";
            $image_name = "img_"."_".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";
            $path = $url."".$image_name; // path of saved image 

            // base64 encoded utf-8 string
            $binary = base64_decode($base);

            // binary, utf-8 bytes
            header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");

            $file = fopen("../uploads//" . $image_name, "wb"); // 
            $filepath = $image_name; 
            fwrite($file, $binary);

            fclose($file);          

            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (path) VALUES ('$path', now())");


        }
```

Hope it helps!